# PHP Smarty Permission denied when edit tpl

Tags: php, smarty

After I edited my templates file, refreshing my browser, it shows:

```
Warning: touch(): Utime failed: Permission denied in     /home/php/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php on line 222
```

And something I edited in templates file didn't show up.

Then I refreshed the browser again, the warning disappeared. What I have edited is perfectly working.

So, can you tell me what happen to the warning?
My os is ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: well if its working now .... let sleeping code lie